# Horror movie where pregnant girl is haunted by her boyfriend's ex-wife/girlfriend

Tags: identify-this-movie

I believe this movie is Thai, or at least east Asian.

In the beginning of the movie a girl finds out she is pregnant, and asks a doctor if she can abort it. Then she goes to a train station, and she catches a stroller that was about to roll onto the train tracks. Fast forward, she finds out her boyfriend's ex wife/girlfriend's (who was killed or committed suicide, can't remember) spirit is inside the baby she is carrying. Pregnant woman then attempts suicide by jumping off a hospital building  (twice!) but she survives.

Also the woman consults a buddhist monk and asks him about the supernatural activity, in which she is then told it is due to karma. The movie flashes back to when pregnant woman's boyfriend's ex-wife discovers her husband was cheating on her with pregnant woman (she was not pregnant at the time). I think this is a movie on netflix, but I'm not certain.

Movie looks like it was made in the mid to early 2000s (so like 2001-2010). This is a crazy movie overall, it's just too bad I forgot the title of it

Answer (score 5):

This is the plot of the Pang brothers' [The Eye 2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0405061/combined) from 2004.

> Joey recovers from an overdose of sleeping pills after having her stomach pumped. It was a close call; she had visions of dead people accompanying her during her darkest minutes. But just when she looks forward to a brand new life, she discovers that she is pregnant. Being tortured by the thought of an abortion, Joey finds herself becoming delusional and emotionally unstable. She is frequently threatened by the sudden presence of strangers, and also feels stalked by a mysterious woman. The stalker actually confronts her on one occasion; making eye contact with her on a train platform, then, throwing herself at a running train! Joey breaks down at the sight of the suicide, only to discover later that "nobody" is found on the track...

She also (repeatedly) tries to kill herself by jumping off a building. Here's the trailer: